# NoMethodError with Devise LDAP and blank User Object Properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I followed these instructions to set up basic LDAP authentication via Devise in my Rails app:
http://blackfistsecurity.blogspot.dk/2011/12/rails-authentication-using-devise-and.html

A first-time log in with an AD account creates a corresponding user in the database, populating lastname, firstname, displayname, and email from the AD account's object properties found by get_ldap_param()

The process is working fine EXCEPT when an AD user has a blank attribute, such as a blank last name (AD attribute 'sn')-- that causes the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create
undefined method `sn' for #<Net::LDAP::Entry:0x00000004920758>
```

The user model is below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :ldap_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :firstname, :lastname, :displayname

  before_save :get_ldap_lastname, :get_ldap_firstname, :get_ldap_displayname, :get_ldap_email

  def get_ldap_lastname
      Rails::logger.info("### Getting the users last name")
      tempname = Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"sn")
      puts "\tLDAP returned lastname of " + tempname
      self.lastname = tempname
  end

  def get_ldap_firstname
      Rails::logger.info("### Getting the users first name")
      tempname = Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"givenname")
      puts "\tLDAP returned firstname of " + tempname
      self.firstname = tempname
  end

  def get_ldap_displayname
      Rails::logger.info("### Getting the users display name")
      tempname = Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"displayname")
      self.displayname = tempname
  end

  def get_ldap_email
      Rails::logger.info("### Getting the users email address")
      tempmail = Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"mail")
      self.email = tempmail
  end
end
```

The error is coming from this call:

```
Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"sn")
```

When get_ldap_param encounters a blank attribute, I would like it to return blank instead of undefined.

I tried addressing the issue with the following code, but it does not work because the error happens at the moment get_ldap_param is called.

```
if tempname.none?
  tempname = ""
end
```

Do I need to modify the Devise gem to do this, or can it be done somehow after the call?

Please forgive my newbness

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the [devise_ldap_authenticatable](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable) devise module.  It's using the [method accessor for the LDAP entry attribute values instead of the hash operatior](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/blob/master/lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable/ldap_adapter.rb#L102):

```
  def ldap_param_value(param)
    filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq(@attribute.to_s, @login.to_s)
    ldap_entry = nil
    @ldap.search(:filter => filter) {|entry| ldap_entry = entry}

    if ldap_entry
      if ldap_entry[param]
        DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send("Requested param #{param} has value #{ldap_entry.send(param)}")
        value = ldap_entry.send(param)
        value = value.first if value.is_a?(Array) and value.count == 1
        value
```

According to the docs for ruby-net-ldap, the hash accessor should be used to retrieve the values like the following:

```
  def ldap_param_value(param)
    filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq(@attribute.to_s, @login.to_s)
    ldap_entry = nil
    @ldap.search(:filter => filter) {|entry| ldap_entry = entry}

    if ldap_entry
      if value = ldap_entry[param]
        DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send("Requested param #{param} has value #{value}")
        value = value.first if value.is_a?(Array) and value.count == 1
        value
```

This is a bug and you can update [the issue you filed](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/issues/82) with devise_ldap_authenticatable with this information.

Comment: I modified the ldap_adapter.rb with your changes-- I can get through the login process now, instead of blank information however it is inserting '--- []', probably inserting the blank rails array.  As you say, it def appears to be a bug in devise_ldap.  I will add your answer to the issue I posted on their git page.  Thanks